# Connection to Oracle RDS database with aws glue python shell

Tags: aws-glue

Need the steps to connect to Oracle RDS database using python glue shell using oracle jdbc or the registered catalog connection in glue

def get_connection(self, conn_name):

```
client = boto3.client('glue', region_name=self.region_id)
response = client.get_connection(Name=conn_name)
print(response)

connection_properties = response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']
URL = connection_properties['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL']
url_list = URL.split("/")

host = "{}".format(url_list[-2][:-5])
portno = url_list[-2][-4:]
database = "{}".format(url_list[-1])
user = "{}".format(connection_properties['USERNAME'])
pwd = "{}".format(connection_properties['PASSWORD'])

rs_conn = orcl.connect(database=database, host=host, port=portno,
                        user=user, password=pwd, ssl=True)
cur = rs_conn.cursor()
cur.execute("set statement_timeout = 1200000")
rs_conn.commit()
cur.close()
return rs_conn
```

conn = get_connection()

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you experiencing? Found this: [AWS Glue Connection Properties - AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-defining.html)

Comment: created a function above to get to the db..defined the connection details in the glue connection catalog.. so to get to the db

Comment: Is the Glue Connection to the database successful? Are you getting any error? Timeout?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-connecting.html)

> If a job needs to run in your VPC subnet—for example, transforming data from a JDBC data store in a private subnet—AWS Glue sets up elastic network interfaces that enable your jobs to connect securely to other resources within your VPC. Each elastic network interface is assigned a private IP address from the IP address range within the subnet you specified.

The steps to setup access are:

1. Create a Security Group in the VPC with a self referencing rule to allow AWS Glue components to communicate and an Amazon S3 VPC endpoint, see inbound and outbound rules in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html).
2. Update your RDS security group to allow inbound and outbound access to the sg created in step one.
3. Create a [Glue Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html) to the RDS source using the sg created in step one and [test your connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-test-connections.html).
4. If the network setup is correct and the connection is successful, create a job using this connection or edit an existing job >> All connections >> Select to force Glue to create ENIs in the specified subnet.